# Windows 8 App Screen Layout

Tags: xaml, layout, windows-8, size, screen

How can I design an app that adjusts to different screen sizes? So far I stretched the grid because on my computer that fills the screen. Will other computers see this differently? Should I use a scrollbar, if so how? I also tried `<viewbox stretch="fill" stretchdirection="both"> <grid width="1024" height="575"` Using this everything in the app looks stretched and zoomed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to hard code the pixel values as Windows 8 supports various types of layout for making a responsive layouts in XAML like flexbox and grids with some others.

Ex. for resoponsive layout in Grid will be some thing like this

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF0C0C0C">
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
         <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 </Grid>


Auto    The size is determined by the size properties of the content object.
*       The value is expressed as a weighted proportion of available space.
```

You can read about more about [here](http://www.playingwith.net/2012/01/creating-a-dynamic-layout-with-xaml-in-windows-8-metro-style-apps/)

I would recommend that you take a look at the following courses on Microsoft Virtual Academy to know more about creating responsive designs with XAML.

[Designing Your XAML UI with Blend Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/designing-your-xaml-ui-with-blend-jump-start#?fbid=8JwRW-NOngk)

[Windows Store App Development Essentials with C# Refresh](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/windows-store-app-development-essentials-with-c-refresh#?fbid=8JwRW-NOngk)

Comment: will this structure be the same for all screen sizes?

Comment: OK. Im not exactly looking for responsiveness. More that the app looks the same on all screens.

Comment: ya by responsive I meant that things inside the columns will also re size (become small or large ) according to the width of the screen.So If you have a large screen the things will be large as they size here is relative to the window size . so It should serve your purpose.