# Windows Store Metro APP how to adapt to screen size

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I would like to know how to have my Metro Windows 8 app to adapt to the screen size.
In other term : a somewhat responsive design.

Using the simulator via Visual Studio 2013, I can test multiple screen and it seems my app is not behaving correctly at all.

I also used the simulator to see how some of Windows 8/8.1 built-in apps behaved : it's splendid and clean.

How can I achieve this much ?

I already found a partial answer for my grid : [Windows 8 App Screen Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036483/windows-8-app-screen-layout)

but it is not enough.

This picture shows what I am trying to do :

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2014/49/1417438224-stack.png

I need to keep that layout, in landscape mode preferably, whatever the screen solution is.

In Windows Phone, it seems to work like a charm : no need to do anything.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: What is wrong in your screenshot?

Comment: Nothing :) It just shows what I am trying to achieve. I need to have my app to show this layout whatever the screen size is. For example, the register button must always be on the bottom right corner. The login part always in the center etc... how can I do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very basic XAML knowlege.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


// Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" - your grid with Login/Password. Use VerticalAligment="Center", HorizontalAligment="Center" 

// Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" - your register button. Use VerticalAligment="Bottom", HorizontalAligment="Right"

</Grid>
```

Personally I'll recomment you to place "Register" button as link under "Login" button.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I will try working with it. My knowledge in XAML is limited so it might take time. By the way, do I need all these rows ? Can I not be working with only one ? Thanks !

Comment: There other designs are possible. This one just the most easier to understand.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, I am starting to understand ! Where can I found such other designs ? But if yours is enough, I will keep it.

Comment: XAML is like HTML. You can try two rows with one column. grid with login data should be aligned to center/bottom (row=0). Register button in the row=1 and aligned to right/bottom. size of row=0 about 2/3 of the screen. <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>

Comment: Excellent. My app is now taking a better form. Working with the rows and columns size is much like the GridLayout in Android. Thank you !